# FT232RL is not recognized on custom board

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ftdi

I designed a schematic with ft232rl chip but when making a pcb, windows doesn't detect my ft232rl chip.
I read in some forums some possible design problems but I can't find the fault that I have in my schematic for which the chip doesn't work for me.

I attach an image of the schematic.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Show us your PCB layout too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT232R.pdf) here is the minimal connection:

[image]

The 100nF capacitor is missing, as Jasen +1 points out. It's stated as "bypass" but it may well be required for stability of the internal regulator. If the 3.3V supply is oscillating that will prevent it from working and might even damage something.

You have only 100nF bypass on Vcc when the datasheet suggests 100nF || 4.7uF bulk (at least as far as we can see on the schematic). That could cause issues.

The missing ferrite bead and 10nF capacitor are probably not causing your problem, but they provide some filtering.